# Pair Of Pro Duo for a Blender workstation

Tags: gpu, hardware

I am building a new workstation solely for working in Blender & am wondering if Blender would recognize and utilize 2 x Pro Duo.

AMD Pro Duo description: https://pro.radeon.com/en/product/pro-series/radeon-pro-duo/

Regardless of it sounding like it may be overkill. Would it work at cutting render speed to a fraction?

And if yes, what do I need to be certain of including in order to make the most of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Pro Duo and I don't see why two of them can't work together. With 2 cards, you'll have access to 4 compute devices since each card has 2 GPUs.

Checklist:

- These cards a really long, make sure your case can fit them.
- These cards are 250W each, so make sure you have a 750Watt+ power supply. Also, they require a set of 6+8pin PCIE power connectors for each GPU.

The rendering performance will scale very linearly with additional GPUs. But keep in mind that you are still limited to 16GB of video memory(per GPU), not the combined total video memory (64GB).

Comment: Please tell me if I understand correctly.  The 16 GB will limit the overall potential size of my scene, however all the GPUs processing power would go into all of my editing and rendering speeds?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Perhaps also mention the power cable needs (6 * 8 pins GPU power cable)